# Weird behavior from capybara when passing a symbol to select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I just spent half an hour fixing error messages I got from rspec when doing the following:

```
click_button 'Create Paste'
```

I tried it with save_and_open_page and the button was definitely there. The error message I got was:

```
Failure/Error: click_on 'Create Paste'
ActionView::Template::Error:
Invalid id given:`
```

Turns out that the problem wasn't even related to that `click_on` call but rather caused a line a bit above:

```
select @paste.language, :from => 'paste_language'
```

`@paste.language` was a symbol and adding `.to_s` fixed the problem.

I am new to Ruby, Rails, Capybara, RSpec and that whole stack so this might be obvious but isn't this something that should have been caught earlier? If so I might file a bug report, but I just want to make sure first.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method): "The select box can be found via its name, id or label **text**".

So you need text, i.e. string, and not a symbol. If you want the method to accept symbol (which makes sense), discuss it with the capybara's author (set up an issue on the project's gihub page) and send him a pull request.